An example of two manifolds whose deRham cohomology groups are isomorphic but whose deRham cohomology rings are not.
The full question is as follows: give an example of two manifolds $M$ and $N$ such that $H^k(M)\cong H^k(N)$ but the cohomology rings $H^*(M)$ and $H^*(N)$ are not isomorphic.
Now, I was given the following hint

There exists closed $2$ forms $\omega$ and $\eta$ such that $\{[\omega],[\eta]\}$ generates $H^2(CP^2+CP^2)$, and $\omega\wedge\eta$ is exact.

My first question is why is that true?
Because of this hint, I considered $\mathbb{CP}^2+\mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ and it wasn't hard to show that they have the same cohomology groups. Now, for $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2$ , I'd be able to write the volume form as the wedge of the pullbacks of the volume form on $\mathbb{S}^2$ along the projections.
Using the hint, I'll get that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^2+\mathbb{CP}^2)$ and $H^*(\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2)$ are not isomorphic as graded rings, which brings me to the second question,

if they're not isomorphic as graded rings, why does that imply they're not isomorphic as rings?


For the first question: since $$\omega,\eta$$ have both (2n)/2 their product is either 0, (if they share a common form)  or a it is a multiple of the 2n-volume form, that is unique up to scalar multiples. Both have derivative 0.

I added a very important detail that I left out.

@RolandF: but you’re proving the wedge product is closed, not exact.

I don’t know about a general answer for question 2, but here, thanks to the graded structure, you can write an explicit ring-theoretic property satisfied by one ring and not the other.

@Aphelli can you elaborate a bit? I don’t see what it is.

Can you explicitly write down the cohomology rings in both cases?

I can for $S^2\times S^2$ using the Kunneth formulas (though, only as a tensor product, I’m not sure if I’m able to combine them). For $CP^2+CP^2$ I know that the cohomology groups are isomorphic to the direct sum of the cohomology groups of $CP^2$, except at 0 and 4, where it is $\mathbb{R}$.

As you already mentioned, you have a direct sum in dimensions 0 and 4. The reduced cohomology of the connected sum is the direct sum, quotient the difference in orientation forms. For your example then, the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^3)$, so the cohomology ring of the connected sum is $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^3,Y^3,XY,X^2-Y^2)$.

So, I get why we quotient by $XY$, but why do we quotient out by $X^2-Y^2$? Why do we quotient the difference in orientation forms, that is?

Let me try and find a post that proves this (I think it's on math overflow). The key point is that the sphere you glue along for the connected sum is a cofibration, and the quotient by that sphere is the wedge sum, whose cohomology ring is the direct sum.

This one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98376/cup-products-of-connected-sum ?

Yes that's the one.

It occurs to me that in the case of de Rham cohomology, maybe this is easier to see. You need to define a map $H^\ast(M)\oplus H^\ast(N)\rightarrow H^\ast(M#N)$, and show it's a graded ring homomorphism. Then Mayer-Vietoris will shows it's surjective, and what the kernel is.

How would I define this map? It seems to me that given a form on $M$, I have to map it to a form on $M$ deleted a small ball and then extend that form to the entirety of $M# N$. Mayer Vietoris gives an isomorphism from $H^k(M# N)$ to $H^k(M-p)\oplus H^k(N-q)$ (for $0<k<\dim(M)=\dim(N)$).

Yes, restrict the form on $M$ to an open subset of $M$ (the one minus a small ball), then use a partition of unity on $M# N$ to extend to the entire connected sum. I think all the ideas that go into proving Mayer-Vietoris will show you how to define this map, and show it is surjective.

Ok now I'm not convinced this is as easy as I maybe made it seem. Perhaps there is no easier way when specializing to de Rham cohomology.
